# How to check if Azure blob exists anywhere in storage account in multiple containers?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cli

I have an Azure Storage account and in it are multiple Containers. How can I check all of the Containers to see if a specific named blob is in any of them? Also the blobs have multiple directories.
I know there's the `az storage blob exists` command, but that requires a Container name parameter. Will I have to use the List Containers command first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to get the containers list. I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-list-examples):

One of the way is Firstly, i have executed below code for getting containers list:

```
$storage_account_name="rithemo"
$key="T0M65s8BOi/v/ytQUN+AStFvA7KA=="
$containers=az storage container list --account-name $storage_account_name  --account-key $key 
$x=$containers | ConvertFrom-json
$x.name
```

[image]
*$key = Key of Storage Account*

Now getting every blob present in all containers in my Storage account:

```
$Target = @()
foreach($emo in $x.name )
 {
$y=az storage blob list -c $emo --account-name $storage_account_name  --account-key $key
$y=$y | ConvertFrom-json
$Target += $y.name
}  
$Target
```

[image]

Now checking if given blob exists or not as below:

```
$s="Check blob name"
 if($Target -contains $s){
Write-Host("Blob Exists")
}else{
 Write-Host("Blob Not Exists")
 }
```

[image]

Or you can directly use `az storage blob exists`  command as below after getting containers list:

```
foreach($emo in $x.name )
 {
az storage blob exists --account-key $key --account-name $storage_account_name --container-name mycontainer --name $emo --name "xx"
}
```

[image]